# implementing custom fromJson methods

Tags: json, flutter, dart, freezed

I am using freezed package for my flutter app. I don't know how to create custom fromJson methods for some specific types.
The ones I am batteling with are: `List<Offset>`, `List<DateTime>` and `List<Duration>`.
I run into this error:

```
Could not generate 'fromJson' code for 'animationStatus' because of type 'Offset'.

Could not generate 'fromJson' code for 'animationStatus' because of type 'DateTime'.

Could not generate 'fromJson' code for 'animationStatus' because of type 'Duration'.
```

Could you please direct me to some examples. Am pretty clueless and would like some examples on how to implement as well as where to add these methods so that they don't need to be generated.